# Использование контролов ActiveX без регистрации

Tags: c#, activex

Такая ситуация:
Есть ActiveX контрол, который у меня работает, а у других пользователей -- нет.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы контрол загружался без регистрации его в системе. Ну, например, прога загружала его из своей папки.

Comment: По идее, можно, вам нужен manifest. Смотрите в сторону reg-free COM. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Comment: @VladD
Хм. Я добавил в манифест следующие строчки:
`  <file name="Flash.ocx">
    <comClass clsid="{D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}" threadingModel="Both" />
  </file>`
В ответ получаю сообщение, что в манифесте содержится ошибка.
[Скрин](http://f3.s.qip.ru/BckmChBT.png)

Comment: Не помню насчет ActiveX, но COM Library можно было грузить через LoadLibrary без регистрации.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Решение нашел.
Я сгенерировал манифест для файла Flash.ocx с помощью утилиты mt.exe, которая идет в Windows SDK:

mt.exe -tlb:Flash.ocx -dll:Flash.ocx -out:Flash.ocx.manifest

Далее скопировал из файла секцию  и поместил к себе в манифест. Все заработало -- теперь контролы берутся из файла в папке. Всем спасибо за наводки!

Comment: Круто! Спасибо, что не поленились написать решение.

Comment: @WGOS, можешь не много по подробнее написать что за секцию ты скопировал из файла? Из какого файла?. 
У меня у самого такая проблема возникла и хочу обойти регистрацию dll, и ocx и по сути есть куча dll,ocx и один exe. Для dll и ocx я сделал манифесты, а дальше что?

Comment: @Jeron, актуально ещё?))

Comment: @WGOS, да, еще актуально)

Comment: @Jeron хороший вопрос, потому что я уже этим давно не занимался и сурса нет