# Как обойтись без регистрации в системе .dll и .ocx с COM объектами?

Tags: delphi, dll, com, activex

Есть файл "exe" и куча библиотек .dll и .ocx (содержащих COM объекты и соответственно в программе идет обращение к реестру за нужной dll или ocx). Для того, чтобы заработало на другом ПК эта программа - нужно регистрировать библиотеки в системе через regsvr, но как обойтись без регистрации в системе этих .dll и .ocx? На ум приходит только как то все через манифест все это прописать, но как все это прописать?

Comment: Разве регистрировать нужно? Не получится просто расположить все эти DLL в папке с программой?

Comment: @Kromster, нет, я забыл написать, что все .dll и .ocx это COM объекты и соответственно в программе идет обращение к реестру за нужной dll или ocx

Comment: То, что они в одной папке это не помогает в любом случае.

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос: "в программе идет обращение к реестру за нужной dll или ocx". Если система не знает о нужном COM-объекте (в реестре нет записи), то как же она тогда загрузит нужную библиотеку, создаст экземпляр объекта и вернет вам ссылку на его интрефейс?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, возможно я чего то не понимаю, но по факту сейчас ,чтобы программа работала - нужно регистрировать через regsvr и все это работает на windows 7-8 ,но на 10 windows уже не очень работает, тк определенные библиотеки не регистрируются в системе (тут уже либо UAC , либо еще чего ломает). Если можно по другому как то прописать в реестре, то каким способом? Мне на ум только пришло как то через файл манифест прописать все это дело, но каким образом этот манифест клепать в ручную я без понятия. Как бы внедрить сам файл манифест в exe без проблем, но что именно прописывать в манифесте?

Comment: А зарегистрировать программно не устраивает? `RegisterComServer`

Comment: @dr. F.I.N., ты имеешь ввиду в коде прописать к каким библиотекам обращаться и тд? Тут только одних "OCX" штук 400 хехехехе...Хотя с другой стороны, если не останется других вариантов, то наверное придется как то таким образом извращаться.

Comment: По моему, манифет не для этого предназначен. Для регистрации COM всегда нужно было иметь права администратора и повышенные привилегии. Если библиотека не регистрируется в системе вручную, то вряд ли вы заставите ее работать как-то по другому. Может Win10 хочет валидную цифровую подпись на этих библиотеках?

Comment: @Jeron насчет Win10 я не подскажу, но относительно регистрации большого количества библиотек, что мешает регистрировать все подряд, что в папке приложения (через поиск например)? Добавили новую библиотеку, перезапустили программу - все перегистрировалось без внесения изменения в код.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, ну ведь манифестом можно свою сборку изолировать от системы и соответственно по идее программа будет работать спокойно без регистрации библиотек. По факту ведь на старых версиях винды спокойно программка отрабатывает и эти же библиотеки спокойной регистрируются и нету конфликтов, но в 10 такая проблема возникает, то ли не регистрируются библиотеки некоторые, то ли UAC ломает. Кстати, насчет подписи хорошая мысль, проверю.

Comment: @dr. F.I.N., ну то, что подряд регистрировать это понятно, по сути сейчас регистрирует все через батник через regsvr, только не много не понял про RegisterComServer. В чем разница между RegisterComServer и regsvr?

Comment: @Jeron не могу утверждать что делает regsvr (полагаю тоже самое). Но конкретно `RegisterComServer(const DLLName: string)` вызывает процедуру регистрации сервера из самой библиотеки (`DllRegisterServer`). Подсунуть ей можно хоть DLL хоть OCX.

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/475853/Использование-контролов-activex-без-регистрации?rq=1

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, да, я уже влез в эту ссылку, но не много не понял, что именно требуется. Через "mt.exe" я сгенерировал манифесты для "dll" и "ocx", но по идее нужно еще манифест для "exe" сделать , но что именно прописывать в нем?

Comment: Параметр assembly с указание dependency на ваши DLL. Посмотрите здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: "одних "OCX" штук 400" - решается несложным парсером папки или каким-то еще удобным вам скриптом

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, cпасибо! Пока сейчас пробую.

Comment: @Jeron, не поленитесь написать ответ, когда разберетесь.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, да, обязательно!

Comment: @Jeron, все еще не разобрались или ленитесь писать ответ? :)